# Cant able to appy <pattern> in logback.xml

Tags: java, xml, logging, customization, logback

I am trying to create custom layout in Logback, using the link,

[Creating a custom layout in Logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168684/creating-a-custom-layout-in-logback)

and i am successful in creating log file.

The problem is when I apply  "pattern" tag in encoder  tag of logback.xml like this,

```
<appender name="appLogFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>C:/tmp.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

 **<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
             <pattern> %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n </pattern>
             <layout class="com.dces.util.LoggingConsoleLayout" />
        </encoder>
    </appender>**
```

it is not applied on log file, which is created, and I am getting content without date&time AS BELOW.

**-- [ERROR]main.java.com.srccodes.log.LogbackHello - Welcome to the HelloWorld example of Logback.
-- [ERROR]main.java.com.srccodes.log.LogbackHello - Dummy error message.**

Actually if I remove class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder" in encoder tag ,pattern is working, but then my custom layout is not working.

I want to apply **pattern** tag as well as custom **layout** tag on encoder tag.Is it is possible?

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your link, the default encoder is `PatternLayoutEncoder` which supports patterns. If you really want to have both functionalities, you could try subclassing `LayoutWrappingEncoder` and add the pattern functionality to it yourself (or maybe with some clever composition).